# how to unpack .tar file over existing directory

Tags: tar, router

I'm having trouble with my **i2p router configuration** and the i2p people suggested that my netDb might be old or outdated.

This are the **instructions given**:

> - You can grab a huge netDb directory at http://mrbamboo.i2p/netDb.tar
> - Stop your router - unpack the tar file over the existing netDb directory of yours.
> - Change the permissions of your netDb afterwards with chown youruser:youruser -R netDb.

When I explained that I was a total noob they said:

> - copy the netDb.tar to your i2p directory - usually ~/.i2p/
>     the ~ is for example /home/username/ or something like it.
> - then run 'tar xf netDb.tar' - this will unpack all files to your netDb
>     directory.
> - then adjust file settings with `chown <username>:<username> -R netDb`
> - thats it - fire up the router !

I don't even know where to start, it's all Greek to me. All I understand is that I'm trying to replace my own netDb with the one in the .tar file.

Thank you for your patience! and forgive my complete noobness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okey I'll try to guide you through:

1. **Open Nautilus** and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>:

   You will see some files and folders showing up, that were hidden before, search for a folder named `.i2p` and open it.
2. **Move the `netDb.tar` file**, from wherever you downloaded to, and place it in the opened `.i2p` folder.
3. Right click on the `netDb.tar` file and select **`Extract here`**.
4. Right click on the white background and select **Open in terminal**.
5. In the just opened terminal run `chown $USER:$USER -R netDb`.

   How? Copy it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (to avoid any typo/mistake) and paste it into the terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

### Done!

Comment: M.Becerra, when I chown  $USER:$USER -R netDb the terminal says, chown: invalid  group:  'steve: USER'    I'm sure I'm missing the point.

Comment: I changed USER to steve and now I am the owner according to properties. Is that what I wanted?

Comment: Okey, let's check just to make sure, in the same folder **.i2p**, open a terminal and run `ll netDb`. It will show you the owner of the file, as well as some other info.

Comment: It's all under my name, I think we got it.